# Dual bound change event type?

Tags: scip

I'm trying to code a simple event handler that does certain things whenever the best primal or dual bounds change (please let me know if I'm reinventing the wheel here and there is already a way of doing this).

For the primal bound I can catch the `SCIP_EVENTTYPE_BESTSOLFOUND` event, but for dual bound I can't seem to find an appropiate event type (in `type_event.h`). All the bound-related events I see seem to be for variable bounds.

Am I missing something? Or should I just use something like the `SCIP_EVENTTYPE_NODESOLVED` event and then manually check for changes on the global bound?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is no event that you can catch for a change in the dual bound. Checking the dual bound after the `SCIP_EVENTTYPE_NODESOLVED` event sounds reasonable.

Comment: Thanks! Now I'm a bit confused regarding the `SCIP_EVENTTYPE_NODESOLVED` event, so I posted a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56795112/162264) in case you want to help.